# How to copy from csv file while select column from different table in postgresql copy statement

Tags: postgresql, copy, output, sybase

I have **table1** in Sybase, **table2** and **table3** in PostgreSQL db. I need to export data from **table1** to .csv file then export the csv file into **table3**.

Data Structure **table1**;

`Name             DataType
 mmc              char(4)
 mcode            char(16)
 muom             char(4)
 mfraction        double
 mflag            char(1)
 mstatus          char(1)`

Data Structure **table2**;

`Name             DataType
 StkID            int`

Data Structure **table3**;

`Name             DataType
 CoID             char(4)
 StkUom           char(4)
 StkFlag          char(1)
 StkCode          int`

`SELECT mmc AS CoID, muom AS StkUom, mflag AS StkFlag FROM table1;
OUTPUT to 'C:\tmp\csvfile.csv' DELIMITED BY '|' QUOTE '';`

But **table3** has 4 columns and the **StkCode** column, I need to get data from **StkID** in **table2**. How should I do it? because as far as I know, the COPY statement is not able to SELECT when COPY FROM file.

Comment: You need to give us some table structure.  SQL doesn't work like Excel, where you just add on a column of data.  We need to see the _relations_ between your various tables.